# Android Toolbar Navigation Drawer fades out on pulling

Tags: android

I am using a navigation drawer with toolbar in my project.It works fine.The main activity has 1 homefragment with a button to SecondActivity.Coming back from the secondACtivity,and pulling the navigation drawer ,the entire screen fades into black color including the drawer.

But on pulling the drawer,I need to fade only the fragment below the drawer and not the fullscreen.

Can anyone help please.I tried out setScrimColor() method but still the drawer too fades on pulling out.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Post the layout xml.

Comment: layout file using:<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

 
           <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/nav_header_container"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

Answer (score 0):

drawerLayout.setScrimColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), android.R.color.transparent));